# how to get the value of a field of a structure which is a pointer

Tags: c

```
typedef struct Player
{
    int *state;
}Player;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Player *p1;
    p1 = malloc(sizeof(Player));

    &(p1->state) = 20;
    printf("player state = %d\n", &p1->state);
}
```

I got an error when try to assign a value to "state".
I have to write more details to post my question, sorry for wasting your time with this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

`p1->state` is an int pointer. You are now getting the address of that with `&` which gives an int pointer pointer.

I suspect you want to dereference `p1->state`:

```
*(p1->state) = 20;
```

However, that will still cause problems as you haven't allocated any memory for that `p1->state` pointer to point to.

```
Player p1 = malloc(sizeof(Player));
p1->state = malloc(sizeof(int));

*p1->state = 20;
```

Be sure to `free` any memory you dynamically allocate.